# Using public proxy server in HTTP client

Tags: c#, http, proxy

I am trying to use public proxy server (http://www.unblockwebnow.info/) to send HTTP request to destination site, say http://stackoverflow.com :)

My HTTP client has following architecture:

```
string url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
HttpWebRequest HttpWRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWRequest.Method = "GET";

WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
myProxy.Address = new Uri("http://www.unblockwebnow.info/");
HttpWRequest.Proxy = myProxy;

HttpWebResponse HttpWResponse = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HttpWResponse.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
var rawHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

After executing the code for rawHTML I get `"pageok -managed by puppet - hostingcms02 pageok"`

If I comment out `HttpWRequest.Proxy = myProxy;` line, I get the site content.

Comment: The proxy address is all kinds of messed up.  Looks like a junk site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work, but not with your proxy (don't know port number for unblockwebnow.info).
Added port number after ":" in URI

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            HttpWebRequest HttpWRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWRequest.Method = "GET";

            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();

            //United States proxy, from http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/
            myProxy.Address = new Uri("http://72.64.146.136:8080");
            HttpWRequest.Proxy = myProxy;

            HttpWebResponse HttpWResponse = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HttpWResponse.GetResponseStream(), true);
            var rawHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

            Console.Out.WriteLine(rawHTML);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work with his proxy, then this doesn't answer his question.